# Do I have to install intl for Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

I've created a controller with `generate:doctrine:crud`. 
My controller works perfect, but when I submit the edit form or the create form, I get an error that the method `getSymbol()` isn't implemented and I have to install intl, but I thought it was only a recommendation.

How to install it on my mac OS? I've uncommented the `extension=php_intl.dll` and restarted, but nothing happens.

Comment: Now, you know why it is recommended.

Comment: it depends on what fonctionality you are using. If you need to translate, for example, intl is mandatory. It is recommended because there is very few usecases where you will not need intl.

Comment: Symfony includes a [Locale Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/locale.html) which `provides fallback code to handle cases when the intl extension is missing.`. I don't know if it provides the function you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Dude please use google.

http://mansion.im/2011/php-with-intl-and-gettext-on-osx-lion/

first result with solved problem